# android how to stop gps

Tags: android, gps

After launching listener by the following code is working fine.

```
LocationManager locationManager =(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, WLConstants.DELAY_HOUR, gpsl
                            .getMinDistance(), gpsl);
```

After some time i stop the listener by the following code

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
```

but problem is it still searching my gps any solution ??? how to stop gps ?

Comment: Remember to accept answers to previous questions you have asked -- you're only at 45% acceptance so far. That way more people will be likely to continue answering questions. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to pass the same object implementing LocationListener that you requested location updates for to the locationManager.removeUpdates() method.

So in unless `this` and `gpsl` are one and the same, you should call:

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(gpsl);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using maps, you have to do:

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);

mMap.setMylocationEnabled(false);
```

Comment: .setMyLocationEnabled(false) is actually what was missing in my code. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the parameter like this GPSLocationListener.this

```
locationManager.removeGpsStatusListener(GPSLocationListener.this);
```

the compile will not be wrong

Answer (score 0):

My listener implemention

```
public class GPSLocationListener extends Activity implements LocationListener {

    @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
//code here
    }

    }
```

when i try to remove listener using follwing code compile time error.

```
locationManager.removeGpsStatusListener(GPSLocationListener )
```

Comment: You need to use the *instance* name rather than the *class* name when removing the listener.

In your original question, your listener is a variable called `gpsl`. Presumably, this is a member variable in your class. If not, make it a member variable instead of local to that method. Then you can pass `gpsl` when you call `removeGpsStatusListener`.

Comment: You can't use removeGpsStatusListener with a LocationListener! A LocationListener is different from a GpsStatus.Listener.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the instance to your `GPSLocationListener` go the `removeGpsStatusListener` method and not the class name.